# Extend a JOI schema and keep the type safety

Tags: typescript, joi

I have a basic schema and an interface:

```js
import Joi from "joi";

interface Login {
  password: string;
  token?: string;
}
const LoginSchema = Joi.object<Login>()
  .keys({
    password: Joi.string().optional().empty(null),
    token: Joi.string().optional().empty(null),
  })
  .or("password", "token");
```

and I have a lot of classes that extend over my login interface. For example:

```js
interface User extends Login {
  username: string;
}

interface Bot extends Login {
  appId: string;
}
```

How can I "extend" the `LoginSchema` object with the new types?

If I do `LoginSchema.keys({ appId: Joi.string().required() })` it fails, as `appId` is not part of the `Login` interface.

Also, I **do not want** to nest the login credentials inside the interface.

```js
// I do not want to do this
Joi.object()
  .keys({
    username: Joi.string().required(),
    login: LoginSchema.required()
  });
```

Is there any way to extend the schema while keeping the typesafety?

Ideally, something like the following:

```js
LoginSchema.extend<User>().keys({
  username: Joi.string().required(),
});

// or
Joi.object<User>().combine(LoginSchema).keys({
  username: Joi.string().required(),
});

// or
Joi.object<User>().keys({
  username: Joi.string().required(),
  ...LoginSchema
});
```

Thank you for your time!